# setting/changing PYTHONPATH in OS Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, bash, path, pythonpath

Ok, I hate to start another of seemingly hundreds of other threads about this, but how do I set or tweak the PYTHONPATH? I'm very new to Mac and the only other time I've successfully done this was on Windows using Rapid Enviroment Editor. This looks like a whole different beast. I tried installing Django and it failed to do it for 2.7, while I need 3.4, so the current path must be for 2.7. Running `which python` in Terminal shows the `/usr/bin/python` directory, which I then can't cd into, let alone find by browsing. I see that my Python 3.4 directory has the Update Shell Profile file, but it has a lot of limitations. I also see other threads mention PYTHONPATH commands in IDLE and creating one of the bash profile type files for the Terminal. How can I set this and not worry about it anymore until I need to run a different version of Python? I'm on Mac 10.9.2. 
"Explain like I'm five".

Comment: Try typing `python3` (or `python3.4`) instead of `python`.  You shouldn't need to set `PYTHONPATH` at all; it does not control which version of the Python interpreter you are using.  Likewise, use `pip3` (or `pip34`) to install Django and friends.

Comment: how did you try installing django?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `pip install Django==1.6.5`

Comment: @sivanes, I added an answer. There are different pip's for  python2.7 and 3.4. You need to specify pip3 or maybe pip3.4 when you want to install a package for python 3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you want to install packages for** `python 3.4` use: `pip3 install django`

**When installing for** `python 2.7` **just use:** `pip install django`

To use `python 3.4` type `python3` `in your shell`.

To see where all installations of  python  are use: `which -a python`

Depending on how you installed the new versions of python  you will see output like:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

If you wanted to use the python in `/usr/local/bin/python` you can edit your `.bashrc` file  and add `export path="/usr/local/bin:$path"`.

Save, then type `source .bashrc` in your shell and when you type  `which python` it will show something like `/usr/local/bin/python`

Don't screw around too much with different versions of python, you will end up causing yourself a lot of problems.
    You should not have to change your *PYTHONPATH*, just specify  which python or pip version you want to use and that will most likely be all you need to do.

Comment: Isn't PYTHONPATH the most sure fire way to exclude confusions between installed versions when it comes to interpreting? At least, that's what I remember about running Python scripts in Windows. Also, I did `which -a python3` and got `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3` is the /usr/~ shorthand for /Library/~ or why does it give two paths?

Comment: The output is just an example, it is os dependant. what does which python3 output? Windows and unix are very different.

Comment: Ah ok, the /Library/etc path. Thank you for the explanations!

Comment: No worries, if you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Comment: @sivanes, On OS X using the python.org installers, `/usr/local/bin/python3.4` is indeed a shortcut for `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4` and, if python3.4 is the most recently installed version of python3, so is `/usr/local/bin/python3`.  By default, the python.org installers try to add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin` to your shell `PATH` environment variable which determines which directories are searched for command line executables, like `python3`.  `PYTHONPATH` augments Python's `sys.path`, the search path for imports.

Answer (score 1):

To update PYTHONPATH you can run from the terminal:

```
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/desired/path/to/add
```

Then to check the updated PYTHONPATH you can run:

```
    echo $PYTHONPATH
```

I'm not sure if this completely answers your question, but this is one way to make sure modules are visible to python when you import them.